# MS Access: Query to combine rows

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 3 tables:

- Clients
- User_Defined_Definitions
- User_Defined_Data

The `Clients` table has basic information:

`ClientID, Name, Address...`

The `User_Defined_Definitions` has the title for the user def fields:

`StartDate, SalesRep, Website...`

Then the `User_Defined_Data` table contains the data to fill those fields for each client in the client table.

I've built a query which pulls all the data I need, but it pulls one row for each of the `User_Defined_Data` rows that exist for that client. What I would like to do is pull one row for each client, and append as many columns as needed to fill all the user defined fields into the one row.

```
ClientID Name   Address     Description Data
155555   Calvin 123 Fake St StartDate   10/10/2013
155555   Calvin 123 Fake St SalesRep    Tom
155555   Calvin 123 Fake St Website     http://www.fakesite.com
155556   Steve  456 Root Rd StartDate   8/5/2013
155557   Kathy  715 Main St StartDate   5/5/2010
155557   Kathy  715 Main St SalesRep    Jessica
155557   Kathy  715 Main St Website     http://www.fakesite2.com
155558   Jenny  345 Fake St StartDate   9/9/2012
155558   Jenny  345 Fake St Website     http://www.fakesite3.com
```

The first three columns come from the `Client` table. The `Description` column comes from the `User_Defined_Definitions` table. And the `Data` comes from the `User_Defined_Data` table.

And I'd like to see it similar to this

```
ClientID    Name    Address StartDate   SalesRep    Website
155555  Calvin  123 Fake St 10/10/2013  Tom         http://www.fakesite.com
155556  Steve   456 Root Rd 8/5/2013        
155557  Kathy   715 Main St 5/5/2010    Jessica     http://www.fakesite2.com
155558  Jenny   345 Fake St 9/9/2012                http://www.fakesite3.com
```

I know this is possible using sql, but I've just usually written scripts to deal with the data after the export. But this time I need to be able to do it in Access so the table can be re-opened 2 months from now and it will re-query the data in the same way.

Let me know if there's anything else I can provide to help get the right result.

**ADDON**

I took the long way around and made individual queries for each of the UDF's, then consolidated them all by running a query agains't each to place them all in one line. I am still curious how to do this with SQL though because right now I'm in the midst of changing CRM and Accounting software for my organization, and it's become a daunting task.

Here's the query I was using to pull the UDFs onto separate lines like outlined above.

```
SELECT dbo_AMGR_Client_Tbl.Client_Id, dbo_AMGR_Client_Tbl.Name,
dbo_AMGR_Client_Tbl.Address_Line_1, dbo_AMGR_Client_Tbl.Address_Line_2, 
dbo_AMGR_Client_Tbl.City, dbo_AMGR_Client_Tbl.State_Province, 
dbo_AMGR_Client_Tbl.Zip_Code, dbo_AMGR_User_Field_Defs_Tbl.Description, 
dbo_AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl.DateCol, dbo_AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl.NumericCol, 
dbo_AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl.AlphaNumericCol
FROM dbo_AMGR_User_Field_Defs_Tbl INNER JOIN (dbo_AMGR_Client_Tbl INNER JOIN 
dbo_AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl ON dbo_AMGR_Client_Tbl.Client_Id = 
dbo_AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl.Client_Id) ON (dbo_AMGR_User_Field_Defs_Tbl.Type_Id = 
dbo_AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl.Type_Id) AND (dbo_AMGR_User_Field_Defs_Tbl.Code_Id = 
dbo_AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl.Code_Id)
GROUP BY dbo_AMGR_Client_Tbl.Name_Type, dbo_AMGR_Client_Tbl.Client_Id, 
dbo_AMGR_Client_Tbl.Name, dbo_AMGR_Client_Tbl.Address_Line_1, 
dbo_AMGR_Client_Tbl.Address_Line_2, dbo_AMGR_Client_Tbl.City, 
dbo_AMGR_Client_Tbl.State_Province, dbo_AMGR_Client_Tbl.Zip_Code, 
dbo_AMGR_User_Field_Defs_Tbl.Description, dbo_AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl.DateCol, 
dbo_AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl.NumericCol, dbo_AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl.AlphaNumericCol
HAVING (((dbo_AMGR_Client_Tbl.Name_Type)="C") AND ((dbo_AMGR_Client_Tbl.Name) Not Like "*HOUSE*"))
ORDER BY dbo_AMGR_Client_Tbl.Name;
```

Comment: can you post your existing query?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have multiple rows related to one `clientID` in the `User_Defined_Data` table.

Why don't you rebuild that table so that it contains all the fields you require and is one-to one with `Clients`?

Otherwise you may use `CASE` statement in your query and filter its contents by `description`.

Comment: How would you go about using a CASE statement agains't the description. I see what you're getting at about "If this row's description is equal to SalesRep, then place it in column 13, etc.." but how would you go about that? Thx

Comment: Actually in MS Access you would use `Iif()` statement rather than `case` (MS SQL). Generally working with access is a pain. Can you share the actual db or list the 3 tables samples? I may have misunderstood your initial question but if I have actual tables with data I could see if I could help.